# IBM Connections Profiles Widget Edit Mode

Tags: ibm-connections

I have multiple widgets that appear in profiles that I'd like users to be able to configure in their own profile. For this i'd like to use the iWidget edit mode. Is this supported in profiles/myProfileView? I haven't yet been able to get the Edit option to appear in the widget actions menu however can change modes programatically.

What are the requirements to add edit mode to a profiles widget?

So far, I've added edit to the widgetDef in widgets-config.xml:

```
<widgetDef defId="myBadgeId" url="/App/myBadge.xml" modes="view edit">
```

added edit to supportedModes to the widget definition xml:

```
<iw:iwidget name="My Widget" xmlns:iw="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/iWidget" iScope="myWidgetClass" allowInstanceContent="true" 
supportedModes="view edit" mode="view">
```

and defined different content for each mode:

```
<iw:content mode="view">
    <![CDATA[<div id="myWidgetRoot"></div>]]>
</iw:content>
<iw:content mode="edit">
    <![CDATA[<div id="myWidgetRoot">EDIT MODE!</div>]]>
</iw:content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems profiles does not support edit (or search, fullpage for that matter).

See slide #35 in this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/IBMSBT/ibmsbt-webinar130828

[image: IBM SBT Webinar Slide 35]

Comment: Nice find, thanks Markus. This does seem reasonable given there is a whole Edit Profile page which looks like it can have widgets added. However I was hopeful.

Comment: Yeah, it's a tough limitation - there's a million use-cases I can think of where it would make sense for the profile owner to edit/configure the widgets shown on his profile page. However, you **can** add widgets to the profile page (through the widgets config XML file), but these only support the "view" mode. There's interesting use-cases where you can display information related to the user whose profile you're visiting - enhancing the whole profile experience.